# XDocument attribute value

Tags: c#, xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> <kdd>
> <Table>
>     <robel ID="1">
>         <groof NAME="GOBS-1">
>             <sintal ID="A">Sylvia</sintal>
>         </groof>
>     </robel>
> </Table> </kdd>
> ```

how to get the Sylvia?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("x.xml");
foreach (XElement element1 in doc.Descendants("sintal"))
{ 
    if (element1.Attribute("ID=""A""").Value == c.name)
     { 
         //do I get Syliva here?

      }
}
```

Comment: See also: [How do I find a XML node by path in Linq-to-XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458566/how-do-i-find-a-xml-node-by-path-in-linq-to-xml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an *explicit cast* and cast your element to `string`:

```
foreach (XElement element1 in doc.Descendants("sintal"))
{ 
    string currentValue = (string)element1;
}
```

*P.S.* In order to get the value of an attribute you need to use it's name.In this case the attribute name is `ID` not `ID=""A""` and the `"A"` is the value of your attribute.

Comment: if A is the value of attribute name= ID, then what is Sylvia? I need to get Sylvia and not A

Comment: Sylvia is the value of the element sintal

Comment: This solution does not work. It gives the value of ID which is "A". I need to get Sylvia. How to get Sylvia?

Comment: @JohnRyann REMOVE the if statement

Comment: I didnt know that I can get the value just by calling element1. Thanks!