# Read XML to Datatable dynamically

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following xml string that I am attempting to query into a datatable based on a dynamic set of columns. I do not have any control over the xml, it is being passed in from an external source.

XML:

```
<VmapMessage>
  <MessageBody>
    <ClaimId>346117125.01*BR</ClaimId>
    <LastName>SMITH</LastName>
    <FirstName>JOHN</FirstName>
    <ClaimNumber>20222128369154</ClaimNumber>
    <DOI>20131006</DOI>
    <SOJ>OH</SOJ>
    <EmailType>V2</EmailType>
    <AdjusterName>STEPHAN WILLIAMS</AdjusterName>
    <AdjusterId>TIWI</AdjusterId>
    <AdjusterEmail>STEPHAN.WILLIAMS@COMP.COM</AdjusterEmail>
    <SendAdjusterEmailAsHTML>T</SendAdjusterEmailAsHTML>
    <AdjusterTimeZone>-8</AdjusterTimeZone>
    <AdjusterDelegateName></AdjusterDelegateName>
    <AdjusterDelegateId></AdjusterDelegateId>
    <AdjusterDelegateEmail></AdjusterDelegateEmail>
    <SendAdjusterDelegateEmailAsHTML></SendAdjusterDelegateEmailAsHTML>
    <AdjusterDelegateTimeZone></AdjusterDelegateTimeZone>
    <AdjusterDelegateStartDate></AdjusterDelegateStartDate>
    <AdjusterDelegateEndDate></AdjusterDelegateEndDate>
    <SupervisorEmail>BOB.SMITH@COMP.COM</SupervisorEmail>
    <SendSupervisorEmailAsHTML>T</SendSupervisorEmailAsHTML>
    <CarrierEmployee>N</CarrierEmployee>
    <EncryptedSubId>232228520C6IB</EncryptedSubId>
    <ChampionEmail>AMY.SMITH@COMP.COM</ChampionEmail>
    <MasterCarrierInfo>
      <MasterCarrierCode>COMP</MasterCarrierCode>
      <CarrierName>COMP'S</CarrierName>
      <VitalPointURL></VitalPointURL>
      <EmployerCode>00000016</EmployerCode>
      <OfficeCode>COMPREDCA</OfficeCode>
    </MasterCarrierInfo>
    <Details>
      <Detail>
        <Id>0005111*17228*DR3211</Id>
        <ClaimId></ClaimId>
        <RxNumber>0005073</RxNumber>
        <RxDate>20140725</RxDate>
        <DateEntered>20140917</DateEntered>
        <FillNumber></FillNumber>
        <ServiceType></ServiceType>
        <NDC>72344299106</NDC>
        <GPI>75100012333720</GPI>
        <DrugClass>*SKELETAL MUSCLE RELAXANTS*</DrugClass>
        <ServiceDescription>CYCLOBENZAPR CRE 20MG/GM</ServiceDescription>
        <Quantity>60</Quantity>
        <UnitOfMeasure></UnitOfMeasure>
        <NumberOfRefills>0</NumberOfRefills>
        <DaysSupply>30</DaysSupply>
        <BillToCarrierAmount>0</BillToCarrierAmount>
        <InvoiceAmount>188.77</InvoiceAmount>
        <PrescriberNumber></PrescriberNumber>
        <PrescriberName>SMITH, JOHN F MD</PrescriberName>
        <PrescriberPhone></PrescriberPhone>
        <DAW>0</DAW>
        <BrandGeneric>MULTISOURCE</BrandGeneric>
        <ICD9></ICD9>
        <DiagnosisDesc></DiagnosisDesc>
        <HCPC></HCPC>
        <RejectCode>75S75</RejectCode>
        <RejectReason>FM - Missing Pharmacy Telephone NumberüNDC NOT COVERED</RejectReason>
        <PharmacyName>JOHN SMITH MD</PharmacyName>
        <PharmacyPhysAddress1>6222 N SECOND ST</PharmacyPhysAddress1>
        <PharmacyPhysAddress2></PharmacyPhysAddress2>
        <PharmacyPhysCity>FRESNO</PharmacyPhysCity>
        <PharmacyPhysState>CA</PharmacyPhysState>
        <PharmacyPhysZip>937105446</PharmacyPhysZip>
        <PharmacyPhone>9493342222</PharmacyPhone>
        <StSub>0</StSub>
        <Reg>0</Reg>
        <MedStat>Y</MedStat>
        <RegExcp>0</RegExcp>
        <RejectCodes></RejectCodes>
        <EmployerName>COMP'S WEST STORES, INC.</EmployerName>
        <FirstBlock></FirstBlock>
        <Blocks>
          <Block>
            <BlockCode>75*ndc</BlockCode>
            <BlockReason>NDC NOT COVERED</BlockReason>
            <Instance>1</Instance>
          </Block>
          <Block>
            <BlockCode>76*ndc</BlockCode>
            <BlockReason>NDC NOT KNOWN</BlockReason>
            <Instance>2</Instance>
          </Block>
        </Blocks>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
        <Id>0005111*17228*DR3212</Id>
        <ClaimId></ClaimId>
        <RxNumber>0005074</RxNumber>
        <RxDate>20140725</RxDate>
        <DateEntered>20140917</DateEntered>
        <FillNumber></FillNumber>
        <ServiceType></ServiceType>
        <NDC>72344299102</NDC>
        <GPI>12345678901234</GPI>
        <DrugClass>*SKELETAL MUSCLE RELAXANTS*</DrugClass>
        <ServiceDescription>CYCLOBENZAPR CRE 20MG/GM</ServiceDescription>
        <Quantity>60</Quantity>
        <UnitOfMeasure></UnitOfMeasure>
        <NumberOfRefills>0</NumberOfRefills>
        <DaysSupply>30</DaysSupply>
        <BillToCarrierAmount>0</BillToCarrierAmount>
        <InvoiceAmount>188.77</InvoiceAmount>
        <PrescriberNumber></PrescriberNumber>
        <PrescriberName>SMITH, JOHN F MD</PrescriberName>
        <PrescriberPhone></PrescriberPhone>
        <DAW>0</DAW>
        <BrandGeneric>MULTISOURCE</BrandGeneric>
        <ICD9></ICD9>
        <DiagnosisDesc></DiagnosisDesc>
        <HCPC></HCPC>
        <RejectCode>75S75</RejectCode>
        <RejectReason>FM - Missing Pharmacy Telephone NumberNDC NOT COVERED</RejectReason>
        <PharmacyName>JOHN SMITH MD</PharmacyName>
        <PharmacyPhysAddress1>6222 N SECOND ST</PharmacyPhysAddress1>
        <PharmacyPhysAddress2></PharmacyPhysAddress2>
        <PharmacyPhysCity>FRESNO</PharmacyPhysCity>
        <PharmacyPhysState>CA</PharmacyPhysState>
        <PharmacyPhysZip>937105446</PharmacyPhysZip>
        <PharmacyPhone>9493342222</PharmacyPhone>
        <StSub>0</StSub>
        <Reg>0</Reg>
        <MedStat>Y</MedStat>
        <RegExcp>0</RegExcp>
        <RejectCodes></RejectCodes>
        <EmployerName>COMP'S WEST STORES, INC.</EmployerName>
        <FirstBlock></FirstBlock>
        <Blocks>
          <Block>
            <BlockCode>75*ndc</BlockCode>
            <BlockReason>NDC NOT COVERED</BlockReason>
            <Instance>1</Instance>
          </Block>
        </Blocks>
      </Detail>
    </Details>
  </MessageBody>
</VmapMessage>
```

Dynamic List of fields needed in output(This is being read in from DB and can change):

```
ParameterName   ParameterPath
AdjusterEmail   //MasterCarrierInfo//AdjusterEmail
EmpCode         //MasterCarrierInfo//EmployerCode
SOJ             //MessageBody//SOJ
DOI             //MessageBody//DOI
GPI             //MessageBody//Details//Detail//GPI
BlockCode       //MessageBody//Details//Detail//Blocks//Block//BlockCode
```

I need to read this into a table that looks like this:

```
AdjusterEmail                 EmpCode   SOJ  DOI       GPI             BlockCode
STEPHAN.WILLIAMS@example.COM  00000016  OH   20131006  75100012333720  75*ndc
STEPHAN.WILLIAMS@example.COM  00000016  OH   20131006  75100012333720  76*ndc
STEPHAN.WILLIAMS@example.COM  00000016  OH   20131006  12345678901234  75*ndc
```

There can be multiple detail records per MessageBody and multiple Block records per Detail

I really have no idea where to start, I've tried a bunch of different things including linq(which I do not know) and can not figure this out...

Comment: try to use in follow steps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458566/how-do-i-find-a-xml-node-by-path-in-linq-to-xml

Comment: You can pass it the entire XML blob as an XML field in SQL Server, then use XQuery to select from the XML variable passed in and use that select statement to insert the appropriate values in your table: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx

Comment: @Jonathan Fields Have you solved it ?

Comment: Have not solved it yet, the solution below is only bringing back a single record. There can be multiple details per messagebody and multiple blocks per detail. See updated xml above and updated output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply below method and pass your xml file path as input

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.ReadXml("Your File Path");
```

You would have data set which will contain respective dataset object for your xml.

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
 XDocument xd = null;
        using (StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(xmlFilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
        {
            xd = XDocument.Load(oReader);
        }

 var records = from root in xd.Descendants("MessageBody")
                      from details in root.Elements("Details").Elements("Detail")
                      select new
                      {
                          AdjusterEmail = root.Element("AdjusterEmail").Value,
                          EmpCode = root.Element("MasterCarrierInfo").Element("EmployerCode").Value,
                          SOJ = root.Element("SOJ").Value,
                          DOI = root.Element("DOI").Value,
                          GPI = details.Element("GPI").Value,
                          BlockCode = details.Element("Blocks").Element("Block").Element("BlockCode").Value

                      };
```

Create Data table to hold records :

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("AdjusterEmail", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("EmpCode", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("SOJ", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("DOI", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("GPI", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("BlockCode", typeof(string));

        DataRow dr = null;
        foreach (var readValue in records)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["AdjusterEmail"] = readValue.AdjusterEmail;
            dr["EmpCode"] = readValue.EmpCode;
            dr["SOJ"] = readValue.SOJ;
            dr["DOI"] = readValue.DOI;
            dr["GPI"] = readValue.GPI;
            dr["BlockCode"] = readValue.BlockCode;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
         }
```

dt contains as below:

```
AdjusterEmail              EmpCode   SOJ  DOI       GPI             BlockCode
STEPHAN.WILLIAMS@COMP.COM  00000016  OH   20131006  75100012333720  75*ndc
STEPHAN.WILLIAMS@example.COM  00000016  OH   20131006  75100012333720  76*ndc
STEPHAN.WILLIAMS@example.COM  00000016  OH   20131006  12345678901234  75*ndc
```

Comment: This is still only bringing back a single record. There can be multiple details per messagebody and multiple blocks per detail.  See edited xml above.

Comment: Also the list of fields is dynamic, I am reading them from a DB, so the next time there may be additional fields or fewer fields.